# Change the image src for multipe images

Tags: javascript, html, image, button, src

Here is my HTML:

```
<img class="image" src="" />
<img class="image" src="" />
<img class="image" src="" />
<button onclick="changeImages()">Change the images</button>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function changeImages() {
document.getElementsByClassName("image").setAttribute("src", "images/image.png");
}
```

How can I make my code so that when I click the button, all those images change?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a [`collection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of elements which doesn't have methods for applying attributes. You need to iterate through the collection and apply the attributes you want to each of its items. Something like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("image").forEach(function(image) {
    image.setAttribute("src", "images/image.png");
});
```